# Duda: Es recomendable usar un clase no como Entidad sino como Funcionalidad?

Tags: java, javafx, clase

Muy buenas.

Tengo un método que comprueba si todos los **TextField** están completo y que devuelve un *boolean* en función de eso.
Mi idea, es que quiero usar este método en varias clases para hacerlo con distintas ventanas(frames), ya que cada una tiene campos diferentes.

La cuestión, es que quise utilizar el metodo anterior en una Clase como ***MetodosAuxiliares*** y especificarlo como *estatic*, y solo le pasaría una lista de campos. Pero el problema es que no me deja, por el contexto no estático.

Tratando de solucionar esto (funciono), decidí crear una clase normal y crear una instancia de la misma para utilizar este método en cuestión.Pero esto me hace ruido, porque nose si estaría bien crear una Clase que no representa una entidad sino una Funcionalidad.

Espero que puedan aclararme esto que trato de hacer. Cualquier duda la voy a responder lo más pronto posible. Muchas Gracias!

```
MetodosAuxiliares ma = new MetodosAuxiliares(campos);

@FXML
    private void btnGuardar_Click(MouseEvent event) throws IOException {
        if (ma.informacionDeCamposCompleta(campos)) {
            Ventana.cerrarVentanaActual(btnGuardar, Formularios.FRM_VENDEDORES_EDICION);
            Ventana.abrirVentana(Formularios.FRM_VENDEDORES, getClass());
        }

    }
```

Les dejo la Clase que use por si quieren checkear algo

```
public class MetodosAuxiliares {

    private ArrayList<Control> camposTxt;

    public MetodosAuxiliares() {
        camposTxt = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public boolean informacionDeCamposCompleta(ArrayList<Control> campos) {
        return validarCampos(campos);
    }

    private boolean validarCampos(ArrayList<Control> camposTxt) {
        for (Control campo : camposTxt) {
            if (campo instanceof TextField) {
                TextField c = (TextField) campo;
                if (c.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    //Tira una alerta informando que campo falta completar
                    validarFalla(campo);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (campo instanceof TextArea) {
                TextArea c = (TextArea) campo;
                if (c.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    validarFalla(campo);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return confirmarGuardado();
    }

    private void validarFalla(Control campo) {
        String tooltip = campo.getTooltip().getText();
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Adm Concesionaria");
        alert.setHeaderText("No completo todos los campos requeridos");
        alert.setContentText("El campo " + tooltip + " no puede estar vacio");
        alert.showAndWait();
        campo.requestFocus();
    }

    private boolean confirmarGuardado() {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Adm Concesionaria");
        alert.setHeaderText("Esta apunto de guardar los datos, desea contiuar?");
        Optional<ButtonType> btnPresionado = alert.showAndWait();
        return btnPresionado.get() == ButtonType.OK;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es simplemente usar las funciones de una clase, lo mejor es que conviertas los métodos de la misma en estáticos para que puedas usar los mismos sin tener que instanciar la clase cada vez que los necesites.

Te pongo un ejemplo, esta clase tiene dos métodos, el primero te sirve para verificar si una lista no está vacía y el segundo delega una tarea como en tu caso.

```
public class ClaseDeFunciones {

    public static boolean arrayNoEstaVacio(List<String> palabras){
        return comprobacionDelegada(palabras);
    }

    private static boolean comprobacionDelegada(List<String> palabras) {
        return palabras.size() >0;
    }
}
```

Posteriormente, la clase implementadora(puede ser un Main o lo que desees), se encargará de llamar directamente a los métodos que deseas, sin necesidad de instanciar la clase.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<String> animales = new ArrayList<>();
        animales.add("Gato");
        if (ClaseDeFunciones.arrayNoEstaVacio(animales)){
            System.out.println("La lista no está vacía.");
        }
    }
}
```

Para concluir, puedes tener atributos y metodos, de instancia y estáticos en una misma clase, pero estos se llamarán de formas distintas.

Metodo estático:

```
if(TuClase.comportamientoOComprobador(algunArgumento)){
    //Lo que deseas hacer
};
```

Método de instancia:

```
TuClase referencia = new TuClase();
if(referencia.comportamientoOComprobador(algunArgumento)){
    //Lo que deseas hacer
};
```

Espero que te sirva de utilidad.

Comment: Me ayudo mucho en aclarar el uso de los métodos estaticos. Pero la cuestión es que al querer utilizar el método "informacionDeCamposCompleta" como estático me tira el siguiente error: non-static method validadCampos() cannont be reference from a static context

Comment: ¿Convertiste el método a **static**?

Comment: Si, pero resultaba que tenia que modificar todos los métodos subyacentes al mismo poniéndolos como estáticos. Así que ya no me tira el error que te comente antes. Lo voy a implementar en todas las ventanas para ver como va :)
Muchas gracias compañero!!